# Google Sheets and performing a Query with large data

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, importrange

I think I have read every forum online, and haven't been able to find a solution.

I am trying to query data in a different Google Workbook. My data has approximately 127,000 rows and has 5 columns.

It seems that `importrange` only works up to about 5,000 rows. Is there any other way to query data of this size? The results would be up to 100 rows, but it is necessary to search all 127,000 rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

divide your `QUERY` / `IMPORTRANGE` into smaller chunks and wrap them into array constellation:

```
={QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("ID", "A1:A5000"), "select Col1", 0); 
  QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("ID", "A5001:A10000"), "select Col1", 0); 
  QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("ID", "A10001:A15000"), "select Col1", 0)}
```

Comment: How would I include the query select line using your method? Would I use another Query() to close it all up?

Like this?
={QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("ID","Contact List!A1:K5000"));QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("ID","Contact List!A5001:K10000"))}, "Select .....

Comment: Thank you player0. Just thought that I would share something I learned from your comment. I actually just wrapped everything in one overall Query since all the columns were the same. This meant I only had to have the select code once. I am now pulling 127,000 rows thanks to you!