# Query importrange HUGE multiple sheets and turns out error

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

so I have 5 separate google sheets, each one with the same title and format [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKacu.png).
There are 8000-10000 rows each so far, as it's a daily sales updating data, yearly may finish with 20000-40000 rows each.

So what I want to do is to merge all of them into another single sheet, and I've tried the following formulas:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAOnz.png)

**Formula A**

={IMPORTRANGE(B2,C2);IMPORTRANGE(B3,C3);IMPORTRANGE(B4,C4);IMPORTRANGE(B5,C5);IMPORTRANGE(B6,C6)}
Results:

#VALUE!
"In ARRAY_LITERAL, an Array Literal was missing values for one or more rows."

**Formula B (reduced the data to only one month)**

=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE(B2,C2);IMPORTRANGE(B3,C3);IMPORTRANGE(B4,C4);IMPORTRANGE(B5,C5);IMPORTRANGE(B6,C6)},"SELECT * Where Col2 > DATE'2022-5-1' AND Col2 <= DATE'2022-5-31' ",0)

Result:

#VALUE!
"In ARRAY_LITERAL, an Array Literal was missing values for one or more rows."

**Formula C (check if is the problem of the code)**

={IMPORTRANGE(B2,C2);IMPORTRANGE(B3,C3)}

Results:
It works.

**So my question is that**, there is anyway via google sheet let me merge all the 5 sheets in one (5sheets*40000rows into one sheet) , or it's not the place to manage that volumn of data?

Comment: The error you are getting generally implies that one of the "stacked" ranges of data is returning null for all columns or is returning an error (which is only one value, whereas you are requesting more than one column of data). If you share a link to the spreadsheet itself, it will be easier for volunteer contributors here who may be so inclined to diagnose the issue.

Answer (score 0):

every importrange needs to be run separately before you use it in your joint formula. the array error you are getting is a result of some importranges importing those 7 columns and those importranges that are not connected output one single cell. make sure you allow access to all your importranges.

Comment: Thanks so much Player0!     I checked the permission, indeed there was one sheet didnt have the permission. However, after I correct all, it turns out ERROR again, this time with¨Result too large.¨

Comment: @You see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56224498/5632629